# Vuejs dispatch resets state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a setup like this:

```
state = {
  ...filterState.state
}
actions = {
   ...filterState.actions,
   async [INIT_DATA]({commit, dispatch}, data)
      { 
            dispatch(UPDATE_FILTER, data)
      }
}
mutations = {
   ...filterState.mutations
}

myState:{
namespaced: true,
state,
getters,
actions,
mutations,    
}
```

and filterState looks like this:

```
filterState = {
    state:{
       filter : [],
       arr : []
    },
    actions:{
       UPDATE_FILTER({commit}, data)
       { 
           commit(SET_FILTER, data)
       },
       UPDATE_ARR({commit}, data)
       { 
           commit(SET_ARR, data)
       }           
    }
    mutations:{
       SET_FILTER(state, data)
       { 
           Vue.set(state, 'filter', data)
       },
       SET_ARR(state, data)
       { 
           Vue.set(state, 'arr', data)
       }           
    }
}
```

after updating arr (UPDATE_ARR was called sometime before) I call INIT_DATA and dispatch the action I want with its data, and for some reason I see that arr is empty as if the state was reset?

Is anyone knows how/why it happened?

Comment: What does the `UPDATE_FILTER` function call look like? Also your mutations aren't ever setting anything, that's why they would be and empty array...

Comment: I added more code, I though what I wrote was enough.. guess not :)
When I reach `SET_ARR` I can see that arr is actually getting updated (in debug). but when I react `UPDATE_FILTER` I see arr is empty

Comment: Thanks, so the value of `data` when you get into `SET_ARR` is populated how you could expect, right? I think you may be running into some reactivity issues somewhere

Comment: yes, and when I reach `UPDATE_FILTER` I check the state (debug) and see arr is empty.

Comment: Oh, the state might not have updated yet, you may need to use `$nextTick` https://vuejs.org/v2/api/

Comment: I'll check that, but i dont think the problem is timing. I have some ui that is based on the arr and I can see it until UPDATE_FILTER is called

Comment: Do you have a `debugger` in that mutation to ensure it's not being called elsewhere? There's nothing else wrong with your code that I can see

Comment: I put a breakpoint there.. and no.. nothing resets it

Comment: You can `watch` filter data to get an idea about when it's cleaned.